# How do I use a base class constructor for a cppclass in Cython?

Tags: python, cython

Suppose I have

```
cdef extern from "foo.h":
    cppclass Base:
        Base(int i)  # only constructor

cdef cppclass Child(Base):
    __init__():
        pass
```

How do I make sure that `Base(int)` is called? The generated C++ for `Child` needs to initialize `Base` in its constructor's initializer list; can I do that with Cython?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's currently possible.

The ability to define C++ classes within Cython (as opposed to wrapping existing C++ classes) is currently  somewhat underdeveloped and undocumented (largely because there's a lot that you can't do).